# How to make Perl download files from the internet in the current directory on Ubuntu?

Tags: perl

I want to download an html file from the internet called www.caveofprogramming.com, and save it in the local directory:

```
use LWP::Simple;
sub main {
    print "Downloading...";
    getstore('http://www.caveofprogramming.com', "./files/file.html");
    print "Finished\n";
}
main();
```

When I run the program, it indicates that the file is Downloading..., and 
that it has Finished.

However I can't find the file where expected.
Actually, I don't know at all where it has been downloaded.

Could someone tell me where this could be and how I can make it that the file is downloaded where I have specified?

Comment: Does the `files` folder exist in your current working directory? The file would end up in a folder called `files` in the directory that you ran your program from.

Comment: `getstore` does not attempt to create the destination directory, if it doesn't exist.

Comment: Thanks!  I  tried without an unexistant destination directory, but just with the name of the file, and it loaded it in the current directory.

Comment: I am trying to find where the error message goes. It's not `$!` and it's not `$@`. It also doesn't die. WTF.

Comment: It actually worked, there's no mistake.

Comment: It should complain somehow when it cannot open the file. I want to know where that complaint goes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Your file is never being created**.

Your directory `files` does not exist in your current working directory. LWP does not make that directory for you. Instead, it fails, but doesn't really tell you about it.

[LWP::Simple](https://metacpan.org/pod/LWP::Simple) uses [LWP::UserAgent](https://metacpan.org/pod/LWP::UserAgent) under the hood. That in turn uses the [LWP::Protocol::http](https://metacpan.org/source/OALDERS/libwww-perl-6.16/lib/LWP/Protocol/http.pm#) to do the actual request, which inherits from [LWP::Protocol](https://metacpan.org/pod/LWP::Protocol). Saving the file is done there, [in the `collect` method](https://metacpan.org/source/OALDERS/libwww-perl-6.16/lib/LWP/Protocol.pm#L105). It does not create any folders, but it does `die` on error.

> ```
> open(my $fh, ">", $arg) or die "Can't write to '$arg': $!";
> ```

So at this point there is an error message. But where did it go?

The [`LWP::Protocol::http::request` method](https://metacpan.org/source/OALDERS/libwww-perl-6.16/lib/LWP/Protocol/http.pm#L125) (which at some point calls `collect`) gets invoked in `LWP::UserAgent::send_request`, [in an `eval` block](https://metacpan.org/source/OALDERS/libwww-perl-6.16/lib/LWP/UserAgent.pm#L188).

> ```
> # we eval, and turn dies into responses below
> eval {
>     $response = $protocol->request($request, $proxy, $arg, $size, $self->{timeout}) ||
>         die "No response returned by $protocol";
> };
> ```

Note the comment. Right below that, it looks at `$@`, which contains errors thrown by `eval`, and stuffs the error message into an [HTTP::Response](https://metacpan.org/pod/HTTP::Response). That gets returned.

Let's try.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use LWP::UserAgent;

my $ua = LWP::UserAgent->new;
my $res = $ua->get("http://example.org/", ":content_file" => "./foo/bar.html");
print  $res->as_string;
```

Here it is, in the `X-Died` header.

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Cache-Control: max-age=604800
Connection: close
Date: Tue, 24 Jan 2017 10:04:21 GMT
ETag: "359670651+gzip+ident"
Server: ECS (phl/9D2C)
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Content-Length: 1270
Content-Type: text/html
Expires: Tue, 31 Jan 2017 10:04:21 GMT
Last-Modified: Fri, 09 Aug 2013 23:54:35 GMT
Client-Aborted: die
Client-Date: Tue, 24 Jan 2017 10:04:21 GMT
Client-Peer: 2606:2800:220:1:248:1893:25c8:1946:80
Client-Response-Num: 1
X-Cache: HIT
X-Died: Can't write to './foo/bar.html': No such file or directory at /home/simbabque/perl5/perlbrew/perls/perl-5.20.1/lib/site_perl/5.20.1/LWP/Protocol.pm line 105.
X-Ec-Custom-Error: 1
```

Unfortunately the status code is `200`, so `$res->is_success` will be true.

**But why don't you see that error when you use [`getstore` from LWP::Simple](https://metacpan.org/pod/LWP::Simple#getstore($url,-$file))?**

[`getstore` only returns the `$res->code`](https://metacpan.org/source/OALDERS/libwww-perl-6.16/lib/LWP/Simple.pm#L78). And that's 200. The `$res` is discarded, so **unfortunately you have no way to know if this succeeded** or not, because you cannot get to the headers.

> ```
> sub getstore ($$)
> {
>     my($url, $file) = @_;
>     my $request = HTTP::Request->new(GET => $url);
>     my $response = $ua->request($request, $file);
>
>     $response->code;
> }
> ```

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot yeah, I didn't actually go looking but I figured there might have been a bug report already. Thanks for finding it.